# How to add a table with data changes relative to a variable in ggplot R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, visualization

I have an example of a plot that i need to get it using the R language. I use the ggplot2 library. Are there any ideas how to get a table that shows the change in values ​​under the graphs

I was trying to use annotate statement with geom = "table", but it did not help.

[I`m talking about the highlighted zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAu4Q.png)

And this is the maximum result I can get by using:

```
plot + annotate(geom = "table", x = 0, y = 0, 
            label = as.data.frame(t(filter(tableData, usubjid == "01-701-1130"))))
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SHLB.png)

Comment: It's really unclear what you want.  Can you link to an example of the output you want, or describe it more clearly (e.g. include R code for the plot and the table, and say where you want the table to appear in the final plot)?

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you share a **minimal reproducible example** - share a little bit of sample data (if you have data named `my_data`, then `dput(my_data[1:10, ])` will make copy/pasteable code to create the first 10 rows of it), share anything you've tried, and be clear about the expected output.

Comment: @user2554330
Sorry, I forgot to add a screenshot

Comment: @Gregor Thomas
Sorry, I forgot to add a screenshot

Comment: A reproducible example with data we can copy/paste is much more useful than a screenshot - though at least the screenshot makes it clear what you want. But we can't run code on a screenshot. Please share some data in a copy/pasteable way, like using `dput()` as I said above.

Comment: Please consider sharing an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).